# Why is the base case of this recursive function equal to n<= 0 rather than n>0?

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

```
def xfunction(n):
      if n > 0:
          print(n % 10)
          xfunction(n // 10)
```

This is the function example I am going through from a textbook, after reviewing information about recursion, why is the base case in this example not equal to n > 0? As only if n becomes less than and not equal to 0 then the function will stop executing.

Comment: Assuming `n` is positive to begin with, `n` will never be less than `0`.

Comment: Whether or not it should or should not be >= instead of > depends on what the function is supposed to do.

Comment: if it would be >= 0 instead of >0 it will result in an infinite recursion because 0 / 10 will be 0 every time.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp But it will eventually be `0`.

Comment: If the base case was `n > 0` the function would stop immediately instead of recursing until it gets to `0`.

Answer (score 0):

**logical equivalence**

```py
def xfunction(n):
  if n > 0:
    # do something
```

Is the same as -

```py
def xfunction(n):
  if n <= 0: return
  # do something
```

It's a matter of preference what the author think reads best for this particular function.

There are many other forms of these logical equivalences -

```py
if not a and not b: #...
```

Is the same as -

```py
if not (a or b): # ...
```

We can prove this with a truth table -

| a | b | a or b | not a | not b | not a and not b | not (a or b) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| T | T | T | F | F | **F** | **F** |
| T | F | T | F | T | **F** | **F** |
| F | T | T | T | F | **F** | **F** |
| F | F | F | T | T | **T** | **T** |

The basis for these transformations and and other relationships formed by logical operations can be learned by studying [propositional logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_calculus).